# Add transitions to isotope items

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to add transitions to div items in an [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) (v2) list. For instance:

```
.isotope-item {
width: 340px;
height: 223px;
border: 10px solid black;
background-color: #000;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.25s linear, border-color 0.25s linear;
transition: background-color 0.25s linear, border-color 0.25s linear;    
}
```

The problem is the transitions I'm adding are conflicting with the transitions automatically added by isotope. This leads to the transitions I added not working and the isotope transition-timing: ease not working.

How can I add my transitions without having them superseded by or superseeding the automatically added isotope transitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-add it manually:

```
.isotope-item {
width: 340px;
height: 223px;
border: 10px solid black;
background-color: #000;
-webkit-transition:  -webkit-transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5, background-color 0.25s linear, border-color 0.25s linear;
transition:  transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5, background-color 0.25s linear, border-color 0.25s linear;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked partially but I realized I needed to add
`!important` to the end of the property to override isotope:    `-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s, background-color 0.25s linear, border-color 0.25s linear !important;

transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s, background-color 0.25s linear, border-color 0.25s linear !important;`

Answer (score 0):

`transition` accepts a list of transition objects (as you've shown in your example), so if you want to add to the default ones, re-add the transitions that isotope adds, something like:

```
transition: width 0.25s, height 0.25s, background-color 0.25s, border-color 0.25s;
```